# Error: 'NoneType' is not iterable. Python, MacOS

Tags: python, macos

I write code that takes the row from address bar and compare with text that I will set

Here is my code:

```
    send_text_to_search = app('System Events').keystroke('history of USA')
    time.sleep(7)
    send_the_enter = app('System Events').keystroke('\r')
    time.sleep(7)
    set_focus = app('System Events').keystroke('l', using=k.command_down)
    time.sleep(7)
    x = str(set_focus)
    print x
    if "my_text" in x:
        print "True"
        return True
    else:
        print "False"
        return False
```

But I receive 'None' in value and 'NoneType' as type(x). Like I can't catch the data from address bar.

So I can't compare it.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see how that is possible with this code.  You're calling `x=str(set_focus)`, so x has to be some string value; I don't see how it can be None.  Unless you have your own function `str()` that replaced the built-in function.

Comment: I can't catch the value from address bar. If I execute x = str(set_focus), then I receive none. If I do it without str(), I receive NoneType.

In my code I will always receive False, even if it should be True.

Comment: Are you sure `keystroke()` returns a value?  What is it supposed to return?

Comment: No, I am not sure. I am new in Python. I use it to input command, like sendKey for Windows.